# SpringRestfull services for Web application(browser) and mobile App

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hey Friend I am learning Spring Restful services for making my Application.I have stuck in one place.I want that the services I am using can be accessible from PC as well as mobile application.

1 )It should identify the request is from mobile application  or from some browser.
2 ) if the request is from mobile application it should send the JSON object.
3) if the request is from browser then it should send the object to view resolver and send the page to browser.

I Have search but cant find and answer.I want to know how It will know that the request is from browser.
Should I send some extra parameter with mobile application so it can identify that the request is from mobile

Thanks, from the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment so I'll just write here.

I don't think it's a good idea what you're doing, you want to keep Rest services separate from your web app controller.
With that said, maybe try playing around with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public ModelAndView getForBrowser(){
    return new ModelAndView();
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Object getForMobile(){
    return new Object(); // W/e object you wanna return, don't use Object, specify the type
}
```

In your browser app/ mobile app you have to specify application/json in header or text/html.

Comment: hey  @tehras thanks for the Idea I got,What you want to make me understand.
But Please provide me link of some site which has given example that I can use in my project.Like rest service for work for both mobile and web